# Plotting a bar chart of a normalised sub-group in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

Ive a (SQL ingested) *subset* dataset of people which are grouped by a geographic region they live in, then plotted by year (using facet_wrap) with this ggplot2 code:

ggplot(result, aes(x=Region , y=..count..)) + geom_bar(stat="count") + facet_wrap(~year)

That works great, however I wanted to see how this compares to the complete dataset. Ideally I want to normalise the counts in each region with those of the complete dataset so I can see whether each region of the subset performs differently to the complete dataset.

Can ggplot2 do this? I couldnt figure out a way. dplyr can give me counts by year and region (count (year,Region)) and I can calculate complete dataset counts by region (no requirement for year here) but again I wasnt sure how to then produce a plot from this.

**EDIT**

Ive done a worked example to help. This uses the storms dataset and plots - by year - status categories. This plot is ONLY for records in August (month 8).

What I would want to do is normalise the facet_wrap to the total counts for each status category (by year) so the bars represent "relative performance" (if thats the right phrase!) of each category for august to the whole year.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(dplyr)

data("storms")
storms <- as.data.frame(storms)

filter(storms, month == 8) %>% ggplot(aes(x=status, y=..count..)) + geom_bar(stat="count") + facet_wrap(~year) +  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90,hjust=0.95,vjust=0.2))
```

Any help much appreciated!

Thanks

[image]

Comment: Difficult to provide code without a reproducible example, but essentially you could group by region, and divide the count by the mean of the count for that region.

Comment: probably you'll calculate your dataset counts by region outside the ggplot call (by summarising data for each year & region), and then swap from `geom_bar` to `geom_col`, which allows you to specify the column height.

Comment: @AllanCameron Ive managed to work a reproducible example now using a built-in dataset. Hopefully that makes the problem clearer! THanks for your responses

Answer (score 0):

You need to summarize your data to get counts for each unique combination of status, year and month. Then group by year and month, and divide each count by the sum of the counts in that year-month:

```r
library(tidyverse)

data("storms")
storms <- as.data.frame(storms)

filter(storms, month == 8) %>% 
  group_by(year, month, status) %>%
  summarize(count = n()) %>%
  group_by(year, month) %>%
  mutate(count = count/sum(count)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=status, y=count)) + 
  geom_col() + 
  facet_wrap(~year) +  
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 0.95, vjust = 0.2))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks very much - that is close but not quite what Im after (I hadnt realised that you could daisy chain group_by in this way). In this instance (which is analogous to my dataset), I want to compare the "status" for the month of august (by year) with the complete dataset (all years) but excluding august. That would then show relative performance of that month to the whole dataset. Is that possible?